# Starting music player intent closes the parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Activity A start muzic player(B) with intent, going back from music player shows the homescreen not activty A.

here is the acitvity in manifest

```
<activity android:name="myactivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
                >

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and Intent to start muzic player

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/"+"rec1.wav");    
i.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
startActivity(i);
```

Expected results: Going back from muzicplayer, activity A shall be visible as per activity life cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem is your **android:noHistory="true"**

please remove this from your **XML**.

```
<activity android:name="myactivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            >

     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

hope this might be help you.

Comment: if noHistory is removed: then a launching actvity A from notification msg will have multiple'S of activity of A. ie: Actity A is in foreground and a notification arrived. on clicking the notification from status bar Activty A is launched. but on press back key old/recent activity A appears.

Comment: use finish() method in your activity A. exactly where do you want to close the activity.

Comment: Calling finish() will lead to original question what I posted above.

Comment: Dont use before music intent. because it will finish the activity. exactly where do you want to close the activity.

Comment: 1. Activity A start  activity B, finish B and return to A